# Defeating the deleteriousness of time

Tags: rebus

[image: it has name]

[image: it has a name too]

What thing I'm talking about?

Hint-1

> it is a machine or instrument

Hint-2

> the answer has 6 letters

Hint-3

> The answer is a single word

Hint-4

> Usually Requires manufacture by human

Hint-5 (avoid)

> (Rot13) Eryngrf gb yvtug

Comment: Five hints within an hour is a *lot* - most people give hints at the rate of one a day at most. A lot of people don't immediately see your puzzle, so giving four hints at the start and one a few minutes later that you don't want people to read is... going overboard.

Comment: I'll keep it at mind from next time. Thanks for teaching me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is

> Camera

Reasoning

> The top image is a **CAM**shaft.
>  The bottom images represent **ERA**s.